# Why function inside function ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, event-handling

There's this piece of code in ReactJS documentation:

```
function ActionLink() {
  function handleClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('The link was clicked.');
  }

  return (
    <a href="#" onClick={handleClick}>
      Click me
    </a>
  );
}
```

Why for example the same thing couldn't be done like this:

```
function handleClick(){
    console.log("The component was clicked");
}

function Component(props){
    return <a href="#">Click me</a>
}



ReactDOM.render(<Component onClick={handleClick}/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Can someone help me understand why there has to be two functions or point me in a direction where this would be explained to a beginner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second version is not going to work because onClick on Component will be interpreted as a prop and not an event handler. You could fix it like this:

```
function handleClick(){
    console.log("The component was clicked");
}

function Component(props){
    return <a href="#" onClick={handlerClick}>Click me</a>
}

ReactDOM.render(<Component />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Now, why not use two functions instead of one main with handler inside? Well you can but this version lacks code encapsulation. `ActionLink` in your first version is a concrete unit that embodies everything it needs while in the second snippet, `Component` is basically useless without additional `handleClick` function.

Comment: Ohhh right, so when you pass anything to a component, it is a prop.

Comment: Yes, that's right. Plus in React 16 component can return multiple elements without common wrapper. So whatever you define on component is a prop.

Comment: What does that handleClick(e) mean? I know that e stands for event, but I'm not passing any arguments to it?

Comment: This is event object. Event handler `handleClick` is called with this parameter. `onClick={handleClick}` it means that you pass reference to the function as event handler. React will call this function with event object as a parameter when event occures.

Answer (score 0):

`ActionLink` is a component/class type. It allows for encapsulation and code reuse of all of the behavior needed for that link. If it was a free function, it would loose that OO design tenant.

Comment: It's a component? They didn't say it in the docs and I'm having hard time understanding this, what about the handleClick(e), I know the (e) stands for event but how does it exactly work since it is never passed as an argument to the handleclick(e) function?